# Use AJAX to pass the value from the text box to Controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the Edit page where I am trying to update only one field the view is like below. I am allowing the users to update only one field the Quantity of the item, `OrderQuantity` is the field

```
...
   <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="OrderQuantity" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="OrderQuantity" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="OrderQuantity" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</form>
<form asp-action="EditItem">
    <input type="hidden" id="inventoryorderId" name="inventoryorderId" value="@Model.InventoryOrderId" />
    <input type="hidden" id="inventoryId" name="inventoryId" value="@Model.InventoryId" />
    <input type="hidden" id="orderedQuantity" name="orderedQuantity" value="OrderQuantity" />
    <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
</form>
```

I need to pass the newly entered value to the `EditItem` action method because based on the newly entered value I need to update the inventory Quantity accordingly like below

```
public async Task<IActionResult> EditItem(int? inventoryorderId, int? 
inventoryId, int? orderedQuantity)
{
    var inventoryOrder = await _context.InventoryOrders
         .FirstOrDefaultAsync(io => io.InventoryOrderId == inventoryorderId);
    int curentQuantity = inventoryOrder.OrderQuantity;
    inventoryOrder.OrderQuantity = (int)orderedQuantity;
     _context.SaveChanges();

    var intData = await _context.Inventories.FindAsync(inventoryId);
    if ((int)orderedQuantity > curentQuantity)
    {
        intData.QuantityAvailable = intData.QuantityAvailable - ((int)orderedQuantity- curentQuantity);
        _context.Update(intData);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    else if ((int)orderedQuantity < curentQuantity)
    {
        intData.QuantityAvailable = intData.QuantityAvailable + (curentQuantity - (int)orderedQuantity);
        _context.Update(intData);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Orders", new { custEmail = "xyz@ff.org" });
}
```

The issue I am unable to pass the newly/updated user entered value to the action method

```
<input type="hidden" id="orderedQuantity" name="orderedQuantity" value="OrderQuantity" />
```

this passes `null` value to `orderedQuantity`  to the EditItem action

```
<input type="hidden" id="orderedQuantity" name="orderedQuantity" value="@Model.OrderQuantity" />
```

passes the old value `orderedQuantity` that is in the DB to the Edit Action

How can I capture what is that the user entered and pass it to the controller so I can perform some calculation

***** EDIT ******

I tried to remove two form and now have only one form like

```
<form asp-action="EditItem">
 <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
 ..............
 <div class="form-group">
   <label asp-for="OrderQuantity" class="control-label"></label>
   <input asp-for="OrderQuantity" class="form-control" />
   <span asp-validation-for="OrderQuantity" class="text-danger"></span>
 </div>
    
  <input type="hidden" id="orderId" name="orderId" value="@Model.OrderId" />
   <input type="hidden" id="inventoryorderId" name="inventoryorderId" value="@Model.InventoryOrderId" />
   <input type="hidden" id="inventoryId" name="inventoryId" value="@Model.InventoryId" />
   <input type="hidden" id="orderedQuantity" name="orderedQuantity" value="OrderQuantity" />
   <input type="submit" value="Edit" /> 
    </form>
```

Even now the user entered `OrderQuantity` is coming as null

Answer (score 0):

The issue will most likely be this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="orderedQuantity" name="orderedQuantity" value="OrderQuantity" />
```

Your hidden input's value is the string "OrderQuantity". You can set the initial value using "@Model.OrderQuantity" but that won't relay changes made in your input control.

Normally the input controls editing the given model would be contained within the Form that they are submitted under. You appear to have two Forms, where the second is used to submit changes. (Is the first form ever submitted?) If the two forms are necessary, then you can wire up a JavaScript event on your input control to update the value on the orderQuantity hidden input after a change so that this value can be submitted with the second form. You will probably want to be careful about the naming of the fields/parameters between the two forms to ensure any situations where IDs might be repeated are avoided.

Comment: Sorry,I am not sure I am following I have only one form to update the record, there are not twoforms for editing/updating

Comment: @ I tried to explain that I tried passing the user entered value to action  `value="OrderQuantity"` - his passed null value and by doing `value="@Model.OrderQuantity"` passed again whatever was in the DB not the value that user entered

Comment: There are (at least) two forms declared: `</form> <-end of one form then <form asp-action="EditItem">` Your input control for that field is inside the scope of the first form `<input asp-for="OrderQuantity" class="form-control" />` `asp-for` is what ASP,Net links the value to when editing. Because this control is not within the form that is being submitted, that hidden control simply tries to pass the string "OderQuantity". If you want to submit from that second form you need to script an event handler on your input control to copy it's value across to the hidden control when it changes.

Comment: I was not sure if I can pass the values to the button with in the same form so created a new one and trying to pass. Can I have the button within the same for and still access the values. Can you pease give an aexample how I can pass within the same form

Comment: I tried to change the form in to one single one but still I am having the same behavior on the `<input type="hidden">` `value="OrderQuantity"` this passed null value and by doing `value="@Model.OrderQuantity"` passed again whatever was in the DB not the value that user entered on the page

Comment: Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: If you use a single form you get rid of the hidden input. The value will be served by the `<input asp-for="OrderQuantity"...>` field where you are actually entering a value.